# What do I need to do in my view to make Prism.Uno work with x:Bind?

Tags: prism, uno-platform, winui

I come from a WPF / Prism background but I really like what X:Bind offers. How do I get x:Bind to work with my ViewModel when using Prism.Uno?

I have prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" but I seem to be missing something in my understanding of how it works when designing.

Thanks
G

Comment: Would you have an example of what's not working when using x:Bind? Also note that your View may not be a UserControl at this time see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570953/android-wasm-prismmvvmviewmodellocator-autowireviewmodel-true-is-not-wire-u

Comment: Hi Jerome - I did see that issue but I'm staying just with UWP for now until I can get my Refit issue sorted. Sorry I should have been clearer in my initial description. This is at design time rather than when debugging. It's complaining about the variable not being in my code behind .xaml.cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `x:Bind` requires the binding path to be rooted in the View.

To use the DataContext, you'll need make it available typed through the view, like this:

```cs
public partial class MyControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
#if !HAS_UNO 
        // Uno already defines this event (it will be removed 
        // in the future to be aligned properly with WinUI)
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endif

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            DataContextChanged += 
                (s, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                   this, 
                   new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ViewModel)));
        }

        public MyViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as MyViewModel;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jerome. Old school - just wanted to check if there was a more "prism" way but this will work - thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! This may be something that can be improved in Prism, though, but providing a helper, or even a code generator.